# Make multiple copies of Pandas Dataframe row, changing different column values for each new row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Working on manipulating sales and invoicing data for an online shop. I'm trying to take all the rows that contain a bundle, and add a row for each component of the bundle while keeping all the other column values the same in the new rows.

My plan was to use iterrows to find the bundles, change sku value on iterrow copy, append that iterrow copy to intermediate list, change sku again, then append again, and concat the list back to the df at the end.

I'm sure I'm just unfamiliar with the scope/behavior of the row copy that's made by iterrows, but what ends up happening is all the new rows have the last sku that was changed. Here's what I tried below. For reference the bundles contain a main item and some accessories, where the bundle sku is PKG-[main item's sku]

```
result = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    # replace pkg items with main item sku
    if row['Lineitem sku'][:3] == 'PKG':
        
        row['Lineitem sku'] = row['Lineitem sku'][4:]
        result.append(row)
        
        row['Lineitem sku'] = 'second item'
        result.append(row)
       
        row['Lineitem sku'] = 'third item'
        result.append(row)


    df_result = pd.DataFrame(result)    

df = pd.concat([df,df_result], ignore_index=True)
```

I also tried making a copy of the copy just in case and got the same results either way. I get 3 new rows but all of them have a ['Lineitem sku'] of 'third item'.

EDIT: I was able to brute force it by making a separate copy of the iterrow and resetting that to equal row.copy() before each line as below. And then appending the copy each time. Feels kinda janky but it does work. Would still be interested to hear some more elegant solutions.

```
result = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    # replace pkg items with main item sku
    if row['Lineitem sku'][:3] == 'PKG':
        
        new_row = row.copy()
        row['Lineitem sku'] = row['Lineitem sku'][4:]
        result.append(new_row)
        
        new_row = row.copy()
        row['Lineitem sku'] = 'second item'
        result.append(new_row)
       
        new_row = row.copy()
        row['Lineitem sku'] = 'third item'
        result.append(new_row)


    df_result = pd.DataFrame(result)    

df = pd.concat([df,df_result], ignore_index=True)
```